# Gift Aid extensions compatible with 5.6.0?

Tags: 5.0, gift-aid-extension

Are the Gift Aid extensions compatible with 5.6.0?  I'm planning to upgrade a client soon - they are on 5.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

Andy,

If it works for 5.1.2 than definitely it should work for 5.6 since there is no major changes in financial bit of code cleanup and fixes. However its a good practice to test on the staging environment before going live.

HTH

Pradeep